# Collapsing and expanding UI on click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I want my commentTable to expand on click and then collapse on the second click.

```
  var commentsInt = -1
   @IBOutlet weak var commentsTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if commentsInt == -1
    {
        commentsInt = 1
    }
    if commentsInt == 0{

        commentsTop.constant = 8
        commentsInt = 1
    }

    if commentsInt == 1 {
        commentsTop.constant = -220
        commentsInt = 0

    }

}
```

This function works to expand the table (although it looks a bit clunky without animation), but I cannot contract the table on the second click.

Similarly, I want to expand a textView on scroll (you cannot edit this textView called mainText). So I tried

```
var mainInt = -1
@IBOutlet weak var mainHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if mainInt == -1
    {
        mainInt = 1
    }
    if mainInt == 0{

        mainHeight.constant = 440
        mainInt = 1
    }

    if mainInt == 1 {
        mainHeight.constant = 120
        mainInt = 0

    }
}
```

Yet mainText does not expand at all when I scroll. How would I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are setting the height twice with every click. Try this:

```
var commentsInt = -1
@IBOutlet weak var commentsTop: NSLayoutConstraint!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if commentsInt == -1
  {
      commentsInt = 1
  }
  if commentsInt == 0{

      commentsTop.constant = 8
      commentsInt = 1
  } else if commentsInt == 1 {
      commentsTop.constant = -220
      commentsInt = 0

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it with animation?

Comment: @EverythingEnds I'd imagine, but I haven't done that. There seem to be some posts here that cover that, though.